# DataGrid selected row programatically lost color settings

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

If i click on row to highlight record on datagrid, it select and create color which I prefer,

[image]

```
 <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#0000FF"/>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

But if I select it programatically

```
dgv.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

it lost colors and has default background cell style

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: I think you need to move focus to the datagrid as well

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, dgv.Focus() after selecting index works like a charm!